# Yii - Hiding module name in URL

Tags: module, yii

My present URL structure is as below:

http://www.mydomain.com/module/controller/action

I need to hide the module section of the URL. Is there any way this can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To point the URL http://www.mydomain.com/customer/login to the module,
in you config (protected/config/main.php) under *urlManager*:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules'=>array(
            'customer/login' => 'module/controller/action',

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

To make any controller action go to module/controller/action (as discussed below) you can use:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'module/controller/action',
```

or

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'module/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>',
```

Depending on whether the controller/action part of the value (on the right hand side of the =>) is a set value, or a variable.

So if you want **any** controller/action to go to the **exact** url module/controller/action, you would use the first example. For example if you want the controller/action *site/test* to go to *module/controller/action*, you would use the first example above

If you want **any** controller/action to go to a **dynamic** controller/action you use the second. For example, if you want the controller/action *site/test* to go to *module/site/test*, you would use the second example above

This new rule must be above the 3 default Yii rules as they are read and top to bottom and match the first rule it finds only

Comment: Not sure why .. but this is still not working

I am getting a 404 error still

Comment: Strange... I have updated my answer. Do you have showScriptName set to false?

Comment: Ok.. that worked ..thanks. Now is there a way I can get any controller/action to go to module/controller/action ?

Comment: Great, no problem. Check my edit to see how to make any controller action go to module/controller/action

Comment: Can you tell me how to hide my module name from url iam not able to do this using this code i mam using Yii Framework 1.1.x

Comment: @Hasibur open a new question with your code and I'll have a look

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989418/how-to-remove-module-name-from-url-in-yii

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define any url rules in your config.

Your url rule may look something like this:

```
'<controller:(foo|bar)>/<action>' => 'module/<controller>/<action>',
```

Comment: I want /customer/login to be processed by /module/customer/login
This is not happening with the above.

Comment: 'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>'false',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',           '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',               '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:(customer)>/<action>' => 'customer/<controller>/<action>'
    ),

Can you please correct the above?