# Yii app()->createUrl for view action

Tags: php, url, yii

I use generated actions by Gii in a module said News. I have normal view action that works with an id parameter (such as `example.com/news/view/id/1`).
When I use this line of code:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl("news/view",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey))
```

It generates `example.com/news/1` (if `$data->primaryKey` is 1). It is not correct.
When I use this line of code:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl("news/view/id/",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey))
```

It generates `example.com/news/id/id/1` (if `$data->primaryKey` is 1).

I am so confused! in first situation, this function doesn't generate id as a parameter name, and in second situation, it does! but after manually added id.
What shoud I do to make correct url format with this function?

**Edit:** news is a module. I changed the line of code as:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl("news/default/view/id/",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey))
```

It generates `example.com/news/default/view/id/1` that is correct, but I don't want that default!

Comment: in yii2 use: `<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(["post/view","id"=>$post->id]) ?>`

Answer (score 4):

In config file you have something like this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

this create how to look the URL.

You not need to write the `id` parameter when you create URL because is default. Look on the urlmanager rules:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl("news/view/",array("id"=>$data->primaryKey)) => example.com/news/id/1
```

On module defaut:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('/news/default/view', array('id' => $data->primaryKey))
```

You need to create the urlmanager rule... how you want to look at your URL. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306546/yii-hiding-module-name-in-url).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
'rules'=>array(
    'news/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'news/<controller>/view',
    'news/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'news/<controller>/<action>',
    'news/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'news/<controller>/<action>',
 ),
```

if you have a module names `news`.

You can try to replace `news` with regex but you will face problems with urls matched by several regexes if your regex is too broad. Use something like `<module:news|accounting|people>` in rules array key and `<module>` in rules array value.

If you need more sophisticated url management, or if you cannot solve your task with regexes, you can always extend CUrlManager.

Answer (score 0):

trying to check it on this directory: **protected/config/main.php sir.**

---

```
urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controll<>er>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

Please notice is that routed well? :)