# how to remove module name from url in yii

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting, yii-extensions, yii-modules

I try to remove module name from url in **YII**

```
http://testdomail.com/demo/user/create
```

I want

```
http://testdomail.com/user/create
```

Where **demo** is my module name. How can I do this?

Comment: You mean `demo` not `dome` right?

Comment: You'll be best off using a `.htaccess` `RewriteRule` for this

Answer (score 0):

You can define any url in your config by making some changes in your configuration file `main.php`.

Please have a look [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306546/yii-hiding-module-name-in-url)

Comment: I already try it, it not hide my module name