# Yii2 -How to remove Module name from url with same module and controller name?

Tags: url, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am new to Yii2. I am getting used to it slowly. I am using a module to build customer data. I have a customer table. My module name is Customer. My controller name is Customer.
Finally my url structure after enabling pretty url is as below.

```
http://localhost/basic/web/customers/customers
http://localhost/basic/web/customers/customers/create
```

etc

How do i remove the module name(customer) from the url?
I want to make something like this.

```
 http://localhost/basic/web/customers/
 http://localhost/basic/web/customers/create
```

My folder structure

Modules

----Customers

------controllers

-----------DefaultController

-----------CustomersController

------Models

-----------Customers

------Views

-----------customers

--------------create

--------------update

...

----Module.php

I dont know how to insert rules in urlManager even after following this: 
[Yii - Hiding module name in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306546/yii-hiding-module-name-in-url)

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,           
        'rules' => array(

            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'module/controller/action',

    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have all you need is [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-url-handling.html) and take care, you are looking a Yii1 question.

If your module name is called like your controller try that:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,           
    'rules' =>[
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'controller/controller/action',
    ],
```

We want the format to be used in the Url is `controller/action`.

With `<controller:\w+>` we "declare" a "variable" called **controller** with cointains words, and the same with `<action:\w+>`.

The internally Yii will call `<controller>`/`<controller>`/`<action>`

> Remember **controller** and **action** are "variables"

If you want call always the same module you will use:

```
'rules' =>[
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'customers/controller/action',
    ],
```

Comment: I tried it .But it didnt work. Not Found (#404) error.